# Turning a single string into a list of separate links

Tags: php, sql

I have a field called links that accepts a list of URLs separated by a comma, e.g. 'www.bbc.co.uk, www.itv.co.uk'

When I then output the contents of the field, I wrap it in code like this:

```
<li><a href='http://<?php echo htmlout($name['links']); ?>'><?php echo htmlout($name['links']); ?></a></li>
```

This works fine when a single link is added but when there is more then one, then it causes problems.

If for instance I have two links, one is www.bbc.co.uk and one is www.itv.co.uk and then I hover over the link (it is a single link of instead of two), it shows as:

```
http://www.ts.co.uk%2C%20www.bbc.co.uk/
```

Now I'm thinking that because they are separated by commas, there may be some way to use this as a hook to split the URLs up but I am not sure if this is possible.

Any help is appreciated.  Thanks

EDIT BELOW

Added some code below as I already have an array.  Can I have an array within an array?  Should I in this case?  Where should I drop the suggested code in?

INDEX.PHP (Controller)

```
include $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .  '/includes/db.inc.php';

try
{
$sql = "SELECT player.id, player.name AS name, age, position, height, weight, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct previousclubs.name) previousclubs, 
        satscore, gpa, GROUP_CONCAT(distinct link) link, email
        FROM player INNER JOIN playerpreviousclubs
            ON player.id = playerid
        INNER JOIN previousclubs
            ON previousclubid = previousclubs.id
        INNER JOIN links
            ON links.playerid = player.id
        WHERE email = '$username'";

$result = $pdo->query($sql);
}
catch (PDOException $e)
{
$error = 'Error fetching details: ' . $e->getMessage();
include 'error.html.php';
exit();
}

foreach ($result as $row)
{
$names[] = array(
                'id' => $row['id'], 
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'age' => $row['age'],
                'position' => $row['position'],
                'height' => $row['height'],
                'weight' => $row['weight'],
                'previousclubs' => $row['previousclubs'],
                'satscore' => $row['satscore'],
                'gpa' => $row['gpa'],
                'links' => $row['link'],
                'email' => $row['email']
                );
}

include 'profiles.html.php';
```

And my template looks like this currently:

PROFILES.HTML.PHP

```
<p>Welcome <?php echo $row['name'] ?> . Below are your profile details:</p>

<?php foreach ($names as $name): ?>

<form action="" method="post">

<ol>

<li class="listleft">Name:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['name']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">Age:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['age']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">Position:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['position']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">Height:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['height']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">Weight:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['weight']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">Previous Clubs:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['previousclubs']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">GPA:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['satscore']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">SAT Score:</li>
<li><?php echo htmlout($name['gpa']); ?></li>
<li class="listleft">Links:</li>
<li><a href='http://<?php echo htmlout($name['links']); ?>'><?php echo   htmlout($name['links']); ?></a></li>

</ol>

</form>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: How exactly does a link have multiple `href`s?

Comment: It doesn't but what I am trying to do is for each individual link, add a href.  Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily split string using [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) function:

```
// split string by comma, returns array
$linksArray = explode(',', $links);

foreach($linksArray as $link) {
    echo $link; // print each link etc
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick feedback.  So does the first part of that go into the controller (index.php) and the second part into the template that outputs it?

Comment: Yes, I'd put "first part" into controller, basically `$linksArray` should be passed to view and "second part" (`foreach`) would go into view, because it is responsible for formatting your output.

Comment: Have added my code and an explanation with regards to uncertain over where to place the code.  Thanks.

Comment: For your *controller*: `$names[] = array(/* ... */ 'links' => explode(',', $row['link']));` and for your *view*: `<?php foreach($name['links'] as $link) { echo '<li><a href="http://'.htmlout($link).'">"'. htmlout($link).'</a></li>'; } ?>`

Comment: Hi Des, your explode worked perfectly but the output in the view did not.  I used this instead `code`<?php foreach($name['links'] as $link) 
{ 
 echo '<li><a href="http://'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a></li>';
} 
?> `code` as suggested further down but there is a space at the beginning of all links except the first indicated by http://%20www.bbc.co.uk/   Any ideas.  Your help has been invaluable.

Comment: Use [`trim`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php) function to remove whitechars e.g. `$link = trim($link);`. Then it should work as expected.

Comment: Links may contain commas, simple explode by comma doesn't work in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
$links = explode(',', $links);

foreach($links as $link) {
    echo '<li><a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a></li>';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) them, then loop through them.

```
$links = explode(',', $name['links']);
```

Then in your view:

```
foreach ($links as $link) {
    echo '<li><a href="http://'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a></li>';
}
```

Comment: Hi Toddish, using the above, this almost works but every link apart from the first one has a space at the beginning.  I see '%20' at the beginning of them and obviously this does not work.  I use `code`<?php foreach($name['links'] as $link) 
{ 
 echo '<li><a href="http://'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a></li>';
} 
?>`code`

Comment: Hi Toddish, got it now, needed to use the trim function.  Thanks very much for your help.

Comment: No problem, glad you got it sorted :)

Answer (score 0):

You'd be better to [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the string into an array, then loop around the array to output the data. Personally, I find arrays much easier to work with than a string. For example:

```
$links = explode(',', $links);

foreach($links as $link) {
    ?>
    <li><a href="http://<?php echo htmlout($link); ?>"><?php echo htmlout($link); ?></a></li>
    <?php
}
```